# Can a question that is discussive be provided with an SE approved answer?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have a question I would like to ask in a way that will not make the answers primarily opinion based but I'm not sure if it can be done.

I am a Software Engineer and basically I see little benefit in hiring Senior Software Engineers from outside the company as the amount of time it takes them to get up to speed, you could probably take one of the standard developers and train him to senior level and just hire a new developer.  I want to know basically if this is naive thinking.

Can this be asked in a question and answer format, or did I just do that and answer my own question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could ask for what you might be overlooking. Or just ask for the benefits outside talent can bring over training existing employees.

Basically when you find yourself stating your opinion and ask for others, you can alternatively just go ahead and ask for arguments of the opinion contradicting yours. If those arguments can be based on researchable facts, it makes for an awesome question.

And trying to find a contradicting point of view to your current one is always a good idea.

Comment: I gave it a go, thanks

http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17975/is-it-counter-productive-to-hire-externally-for-senior-skilled-roles